# Javascript count characters case insensitive

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I have to count how many times each letter appears in a string.
Case insensitive.

For example:

var str = "aaaAAAbbB"

would print "A: 6, B: 3"

This is what I have but it counts lower case and upper case as separate.

```
        var string = document.getElementById("text").value
        var counts = {};
        var ch, index, length, count;
        for (index = 0, length = string.length; index < length; index++)
        {
            ch = string.charAt(index);
            count = counts[ch];
            counts[ch] = count ? count + 1 : 1;
        }
        for (ch in counts)
        {
            console.log(ch+" count: "+counts[ch]);
        }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could change the character to [upper](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toUpperCase) or [lower](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase) case for counting.

```
ch = string.charAt(index).toUpperCase();
//                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

```js
var string = "aaaAAAbbB";
var counts = {};
var ch, index, length, count;
for (index = 0, length = string.length; index < length; index++) {
    ch = string.charAt(index).toUpperCase();
    count = counts[ch];
    counts[ch] = count ? count + 1 : 1;
}
for (ch in counts) {
    console.log(ch + " count: " + counts[ch]);
}
```

Compacter style

```js
var string = "aaaAAAbbB",
    counts = {};

string.split('').forEach(function (c) {
    counts[c.toUpperCase()] = (counts[c.toUpperCase()] || 0) + 1;
});

console.log(counts);
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I don't know why I didn't think of that.

Answer (score 0):

In order to solve your problem, I would simply use

```
string.toLowerCase();
```

And then you can count for each character.

I modified your code:

```
    var string = document.getElementById("text").value.toLowerCase();
    var counts = {};
    var ch, index, length, count;
    for (index = 0, length = string.length; index < length; index++)
    {
        ch = string.charAt(index);
        count = counts[ch];
        counts[ch] = count ? count + 1 : 1;
    }
    for (ch in counts)
    {
        console.log(ch+" count: "+counts[ch]);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [.toLowerCase()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tolowercase.asp) method, which change all the text to lowercase
Then your code should look like:

```
    var string = document.getElementById("text").value.toLowerCase()
    var counts = {};
    var ch, index, length, count;
    for (index = 0, length = string.length; index < length; index++)
    {
        ch = string.charAt(index);
        count = counts[ch];
        counts[ch] = count ? count + 1 : 1;
    }
    for (ch in counts)
    {
        console.log(ch+" count: "+counts[ch]);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var str = "aaaAAAbbB";
var result = {};
//lowercase so they are all insensative and split to get an array.  loop over the array
str.toLowerCase().split('').forEach(function(element, index, array){
  //if not processed before, perform count
  if (!result[element]) {
    result[element] = array.filter(function(element2){ return element2 === element; }).length;
  }
});

console.log(result);
```